# Extract the shared secret from class ECDiffieHellmanCng

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I am currently developing an SSH client and it is necessary that said client is able to exchange keys with the server via ECDH KEX (NIST-256, 384 and 521).

I did some (actually a lot) of research, found the .NET class `ECDiffieHellmanCng`, and was able to extract and import the public key of the server into the class.

The problem, however, is that I can't extract the shared secret without deriving it (`ECDiffieHellmanCng.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey otherpartyPublicKey)`).

Is there a way to directly access the shared secret ("k" as it's called in the RFC papers)?

[Here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5656.txt) is page 7 from the RFC of the ECDH implementation and why I need the shared secret:

> The exchange hash H is computed as the hash of the concatenation of
>   the following.
>
> string V_C, client's identification string (CR and LF excluded)
>
> string   V_S, server's identification string (CR and LF excluded)
>
> string   I_C, payload of the client's SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
>
> string   I_S, payload of the server's SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
>
> string   K_S, server's public host key
>
> string   Q_C, client's ephemeral public key octet string
>
> string   Q_S, server's ephemeral public key octet string
>
> mpint    K,   shared secret <-- this is why I need the pure secret
>   before any derivation

Thanks for any solutions or hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after a lot of research i couldn't find a way to do it so the answer is no - you can not extract the secret.

My solution for the big picture was to discard the ECDiffieHellmanCng class altogether and instead wrap the OpenSSH library in C#.

Hope this at least helps someone else with the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need `k`, then, you just need to compute H.  The ECDiffieHellman class allows you to do that.

```
byte[] prepend = Concat(V_C, V_S, I_C, I_S, K_S, Q_C, Q_S);
byte[] exchangeHash = ecdh.DeriveKeyFromHash(otherPublic, new HashAlgorithmName("whatever your hash algorithm is"), prepend, null);
```

Though that is using .NET 4.6.2 (currently in preview) API: [DeriveKeyFromHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693487(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you are on an older framework it's still possible, but requires using the ECDiffieHellmanCng type specifically:

```
ecdhCng.SecretPrepend = prepend;
ecdhCng.SecretAppend = null;
ecdhCng.HashAlgorithm = new CngAlgorithm("whatever your hash algorithm is");
ecdhCng.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
byte[] exchangeHash = ecdhCng.DeriveKeyMaterial(otherPublic);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried that but it didn't work out for me. Solution might be a certain combination of prepend and append as the key sometimes needs more than one derivation to produce a key with the expected length.
microsofts documentation about their derivation however, was lacking so i didn't bother looking into it too much.
i will upvote the answer so someone else with this issue can give it another try. :)